# Optimality condition of the sum of a convex function and non-convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

**Problem**

Consider the optimization following problem with $f: \mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ being differentiable but not convex and $g: \mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ being convex but not differentiable.

$$\text{minimize} \ f(x) + g(x)$$

The optimality criterion is $\nabla f(\hat{x})^T(y-\hat{x})+g(y)-g(\hat{x})\geq 0$. Take $g(x)=\Vert x\Vert_1$, show the optimiality condition is reduced to the following.
$$\frac{\partial f(\hat{x})}{\partial x_i}=\begin{cases}-1, \hat{x}_i >0\\
\in [-1, 1], \hat{x}_i=0\\1,\hat{x}_i<0\end{cases}$$

**What I Have Done**

Based on my previous experiences to solving such problems, I think the optimality condition could be written as
$$\text{minimize}\ \nabla f(\hat{x})^T(y-\hat{x})+\Vert y\Vert_1
$$
and $p^* \geq \Vert \hat{x}\Vert_1$ when $p^*$ is the optimal value of this problem.

If I treat $\hat{x}$ as a constant in this optimization problem, then it is equivalent to the following 
$$\text{minimize}\ \nabla f(\hat{x})^Ty+\Vert y\Vert_1
$$
which seems to be solvable. If I could get the optimal value $p^*$, then I am approaching the desired result. However, I do not know how to proceed. Here is one random thought.

- Using the relationship between norm $\Vert x\Vert_p\leq n^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\Vert x\Vert_q$ and make $\nabla f(\hat{x})^Ty+\Vert y\Vert_1 $ differentiable.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: The final minimization problem can be solved with the convex conjugate of the 1-norm.